# How to call the desired collection from Mongobd?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, next.js

I am a beginner. I making a quiz. I stored my data in a few collections in MongoDB. How to call a specific collection from MongoDB? I know how to call only one.

````
```export async function getStaticProps () {
   const { db } = await connectToDatabase()

   const questions = await db
   .collection('questions')
   .find({})
   .sort({ metacritic: -1 })
   .limit(20)
   .toArray()

   return {
   props: {
  questions: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(shuffleArray(questions)))
   }
  }
}
````

Comment: Are you saying how would you query different collections in your db ? if so then you will need to create seperate endpoints for example one for questions, one for answers, one for users etc or do you want to use one endpoint to query any collection ? if so then you should pass it through in the body of the request or paramaters have it as an arg passed to the function getStaticProps(collection) 

then you need to just simply have something like const collection = await db.collection(collection)

return collection 

let me know if this is what your trying if so I will post an answer :D

Comment: I can not understand exactly.                                                                                                                                                                                                                     export async function getStaticProps () {
  const { db } = await connectToDatabase()

  const questions = await db
    .collection('questions')
    .find({})
    .sort({ metacritic: -1 })
    .limit(20)
    .toArray()

  return {
    props: {
      questions: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(shuffleArray(questions)))
    }
  }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export async function getStaticProps (req, res) {
    // this is the collection we pass in our query parameters then is 
    // destructured here and I rename it to COLLECTION just so we can see where I 
    // pass it below
    const { collection: COLLECTION } = req.params

    // this is the db connection 
    const { db } = await connectToDatabase()
        
    const data = await db

    // here we pass the COLLECTION
           .collection(COLLECTION)
           .find({})
           .sort({ metacritic: -1 })
           .limit(20)
           .toArray()

//here you should handle how you want the data structured and then depending on that have the results sent with a status code of 200 if all is well
           return {
           props: {
             data: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(shuffleArray(data)))
           }
          }
        }

example of query endpoint 

http://someconnection/:collection
which will be 
http://someconnection/questions or http://someconnection/answers or http://someconnection/users
```